# RedirectView doesn't recognize @RequestParam on Spring 4.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

The code following work on Spring Boot 1.1.10(Spring 4.0.8) but not on 1.2.1(Spring 4.1.4)

**DefaultController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public RedirectView show(Map<String, Object> model) throws MissingServletRequestParameterException {
        model.put("req", "expected");
        return new RedirectView("redirect");
    }
}
```

**RedirectController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect")
public class RedirectController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedirectController.class);

    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@RequestParam("req") String req) throws MissingServletRequestParameterException {
        logger.info("parameter is {}", req);
        return "/redirect";
    }
}
```

Dependencies in build.gradle is following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:' + version + '.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:' + version + '.RELEASE'
}
```

Set version to '1.1.10' it works fine, but when set to '1.2.1', an error message appears:

```
Wed Jan 21 16:13:45 JST 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'req' is not present
```

How can I use RedirectView with parameters on Spring 4.1.4?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RedirectAttributes in your DefaultController Method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
public RedirectView show(Map<String, Object> model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws MissingServletRequestParameterException {
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("req","foo");
    return new RedirectView("redirect");
}
```